# Почему при отсутствии свойств у объекта выдается ошибка, а не undefined?

Tags: javascript, объекты

Есть пустой объект:

```
var testObj = {};
```

Допустим, где-то у себя в коде я пытаюсь проверить есть ли у этого объекта какое-то свойство:

```
console.log(typeof testObj.test);   // undefined
```

Я получу `undefined`, его нет, всё хорошо.

НО, если я пойду дальше и вызову

`console.log(typeof testObj.test.var);`

Я получу ошибку `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'var' of undefined`.

Почему Javascript не скажет мне так же `undefined`? Он скажет только в том случае, если внутри `testObj`, я определю `test`.

Получается, что объекты должны иметь определенную структуру? Но как быть, если я получаю от сервера разные json данные, с произвольной структурой. Я запишу эти данные в объект. Начну проверять, каких-то данных не окажется и Javascript выдаст ошибку.

Как мне сделать так, чтобы я смог написать, что-то вроде(при условии что testObj пустой объект):

```
if(testObj.test.var === "OK"){
    console.log("ok!")
}
```

Comment: `if (testObj.test && testObj.test.var === 'OK') {`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что так описано в [спецификации](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-typeof-operator-runtime-semantics-evaluation) оператора `typeof`.

---

> Как мне сделать так, чтобы я смог написать, что-то вроде(при условии что testObj пустой объект):

Только добавив проверки вручную:

```
if(testObj && testObj.test && testObj.test.var === "OK"){
    console.log("ok!")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

В этом случае объект существует и у него есть свойство, значение которого `undefined`:

```
console.log(typeof testObj.test);
```

А в этом,

```
console.log(typeof testObj.test.var);
```

транслятор не может присвоить свойство и, соответственно, получить его значение потому что объекта, к которому вы пытаетесь обратиться не существует, о чем транслятор и говорит явно - `Cannot read property 'var' of undefined` (Не могу получить свойство `var` у undefined).